# How to package karate api testing test cases properly?

Tags: java, karate

I am trying to re-organize karate test cases to proper folder structure and wanted some suggestions on best practices if any.

I have all requests under request folder without any subfolders and all util features in a utilFeatures package and the test cases are right under features without any packaging.

```
resources
  features
     requests
     utilFeatures
     *all tests under features directly without any folder*
```

So now my requirement is changed and my code base has code for admin and user functionalities and because of that now I am thinking to separate folders in the process to organize it for simplicity and usage.

So any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: the official docs recommend a simple structure under `src/test/java` - you can adapt those: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#naming-conventions - I'll be curious to see answers from actual users